# Django on Apache: ImportError on settings

Tags: python, django, apache

I am serving a couple of Django sites on an Apache2 server using Virtual Hosts. For one of the sites I keep getting an Internal Server Error with this message in the logs:

> [Thu Oct 09 15:11:24.597107 2014] [:error] [pid 8370:tid 140126138050304] [remote 128.30.86.202:15793] ImportError: Could not import settings 'calendar.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings

Here is what my `calendar/` directory looks like:

```
|-- calendar
|   |-- forms.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- manage.py
|-- urls.py
`-- wsgi.py
```

When I print `sys.path` to my error logs, the `calendar` and `calendar/calendar` directories are there.

I have tried running both `wsgi.py` directory and `calendar/settings.py` directly and I don't get any import errors. I tried running `manage.py shell` and again, no import errors.

I have checked that my `WSGIPythonPath` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` includes the full path of `calendar` and `calendar/calendar`.

I suspect that this is a permissions error. The owner/group for all files in the directory is `ubuntu:ubuntu`, where `ubuntu` is the username on the server. Who should the owners be and what should the permissions be? Thanks!

If it's not a permissions issue, ideas about other ways to test this? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... don't give an app the same name as the project. Django chokes on it sometimes.

Comment: It turns out that the error was because it was looking in Python's calendar library for settings before it looked in the application. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It's good you've solved the problem. It's really not a clever idea to use names of existing python libraries for own projects.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your `wsgi.py`:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/full/path/to/calendar/')
sys.path.append('/full/path/to/calendar/calendar')

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "calendar.settings"
```

The last line should be actually already there. Uncomment it if needed. If there is a line like:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "calendar.settings")
```

then comment it. Try again with these settings and tell us please what happened.

/full/path/to should be replaced with the full path to your project, but that's probably obvious to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have put this before, but this is pretty much what I have in my wsgi.py. Ideas about what else to try? Thanks!